# passing path parameter/variable from batch file to python, sys.argv[] ony gives last dir and not the whole string

Tags: python, batch-file, path, sys

I have created a custom command `scan` for the windows terminal. My goal is to automatically move my scans to a certain dir. I will hardcode my path but in case I want to move my scans to a different dir I have included a parameter2 (parameter1 is "start" to execute). My batch file passes the path as a string to my python script.

I know this because when I write

```
scan start "C:/path/to/target/dir/"
```

into my windows terminal it spits out the following to run my script.

```
python "C:\Users\MY USERNAME\my_scripts\scan.py" start C:/path/to/target/dir/
```

Unfortunatly I am not able to "read" the whole path with the following code:

```
print(Path(sys.argv[2]).stem)
```

In this case the result is `dir`

`print(Path(sys.argv[0]).stem)` = `scan`

`print(Path(sys.argv[1]).stem)` = `start`

`print(Path(sys.argv[2]).stem)` = `dir`

Why do I not get the whole path and how do I get it? I want something like this:

`print(Path(sys.argv[2]).stem)` = `C:/path/to/target/dir/`

Comment: Why are you using `stem`? It does exactly what you show, i.e. there’s nothing wrong/unexpected about the output produced; if you want different results don’t use `stem`. Read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=stem#pathlib.PurePath.stem

Comment: @barny, as I am a beginner to prgramming and python I am not as familiar with a lot of the modules available and I find it difficult to find out where my problem could come from. Now that you mention it I feel like an idiot :D But I will remind myself to read the documentation more often. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed reading the whole path. But then you are stemming it, shortening to dir. Use the following

```
print(Path(sys.argv[1]))
```